# Explain large ramification index or enough ramification or sufficient ramification?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let us consider the rational number field $ \mathbb{Q}$ and its finite extension $ K$.

I can't understand the concept of **large ramification index** or **enough Ramification**  or s**ufficient Ramification.**

Let $A$ be Dedekind domain, $K$ be its fraction field and let $L$ be finite extension of $K$ of degree $n$. Let $B$ be the integral closure of $A$.

Let $P$ be a nonzero prime ideal of $A$. The lofting (also called extension) of $P$ to $B$ is the ideal $PB$. Now the ideal $PB$ may not be prime ideal of $B$ but since it is a Dedekind domain , we can express it as a product of prime ideals in $B$ i.e., $$ PB=\prod_{i=1}^{g} P_i^{e_i} $$ where $P_i$ are distinct prime ideals of $B$ and $e_i$ are positive integers.

This Phenomenon is called Ramification.

But my question is what is **Enough Ramification or large ramification (index)**?

**Please explain this fact with one example.**

Thanks

Comment: Hi! Welcome on Math.SE! In order to help people in answering your question, can you add a definition of ramification to your question?

Comment: ramification theory and field extension is a popular topic . I don't think ramification has particular definition. But it can be roughly say that every non zero prime ideals in a dedekind domain factors uniquely

Comment: That is NOT at all what ramification means! It most definitely has a particular definition, e.g., referring to a prime number factoring in the ring of integers of a number field with a repeated prime ideal factor.

Comment: @KCd, that is true. However I have written something and edited my question. please see it and help me

Comment: Your edit sets up useful notation, but still does not say what it means for $P$ to ramify in $L$. What you wrote sounds like the phenomenon of factoring is ramification, but that is not correct, e.g., in $\mathbf Z[i]$ we have $(5) = (1+2i)(1-2i)$ so the prime $5$ in $\mathbf Z$ is not prime in $\mathbf Z[i]$, but it us not ramified either. Any algebraic number theory book will correctly define ramification. It feels like you don't know examples when you describe the definition incorrectly.

Comment: By the way, your username is misspelled: the math term is Non-Archimedean.

Comment: do you have examples of other people using the words "enough ramification" or "sufficient ramification" ?

Comment: @mercio, Here the word  $ \ Enough \ \ or \ \ sufficient \ $ means large ramification index

Comment: the positive integer $e_i$ is the ramification index of $P_i$. If that number is large we can also say there is a lot of ramification.

Comment: @mercio, Can you please explain this fact with a example ? Thanks

Comment: If KCd has never heard the phrase *Enough Ramification* then the concept does not exist. Is this possibly something you (mis)translated from another language? The only remotely related sounding term I have heard is *totally ramified*. Something that happens when $g=1$, and $e_1$ is equal to the extension degree $[L:K]$. The textbook example being $K=\Bbb{Q}$, $L=\Bbb{Q}(\zeta)$ with $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/p^n}$, $p$ a prime number. Then with $P=p\Bbb{Z}$ we get $P=\mathfrak{p}^{[L:K]}$, where $\mathfrak{p}$ is the prime ideal generated by $(1-\zeta)$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I latter mentioned the word $ \ \text{ large ramification index.}$ Please see my question again. I know what is totally ramification but I want explanation of large ramification index

Comment: You mentioning the word does not define it (or make it exist in the literature). Another possibility could be *higher ramification groups* and *upper numbering*. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramification_group) for starters.

Comment: I would say that “enough ramification” is not a precise technical term. Whether a ramification index is “large” would depend on the task at hand, I suppose. If you could give an extended quote of a passage in which one of these appears, we might be able to help.